# How to get site information by site url

Tags: sharepoint-server, url, web-application

I`m making windows application.

I already built a code about sharepoint site analysis and have 2 program.

1. First program.

   Get all sharepoint site information from PC and saved datas to Database.
2. Second program.

   Write a site url in text box and click button, matched data(from DB)
   showed in datagridview.

Now I try to merge this program and want to this.

Using second program, write a site url in text box then start to find matched site information and saved DataBase then Showed it to Datagridview.

But Im not good at Sharepoint I don`t know how can I get information from URL...

I add my first code below..

```
 private static void bindWebApplication()
        {
            var service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>(string.Empty);
            List<ListInfos> AllListInfo = new List<ListInfos>();

            // Application
            foreach (SPWebApplication webApplication in service.WebApplications)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (SPContentDatabase contentDatabase in webApplication.ContentDatabases)
                    {
                        // SiteCollection
                        foreach (SPSite site in webApplication.Sites)
                        {
                            foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                            {
                                foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
                                {
                                    _StatusString = Constants.STATUSEXAMSTRING;

                                    if (!list.Hidden && list.BaseTemplate != SPListTemplateType.DataSources && web.WebTemplate != "SRCHCEN" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(list.DefaultViewUrl))
                                    {
                                        string listTitle = GetListName(list);
                                        if (
                                            (
                                                listTitle != "WorkflowTasks" && listTitle != "masterpage"
                                                && listTitle != "Pages" && listTitle != "SitePages"
                                                && listTitle != "fpdatasources" && listTitle != "ReusableContent"
                                                && listTitle != "FormServerTemplates" && listTitle != "Style Library"
                                            //&& listTitle != "Reports List" && listTitle != "SearchCenter"
                                            //&& listTitle != "SearchResults"
                                            )
                                            &&
                                            (
                                                list.BaseTemplate != SPListTemplateType.MasterPageCatalog
                                                && list.BaseTemplate != SPListTemplateType.DataSources
                                                && list.BaseTemplate.ToString() != "1301"
                                                && list.BaseTemplate.ToString() != "10022"
                                                && list.BaseTemplate.ToString() != "10021"
                                                && !list.DefaultViewUrl.Contains("/Style Library/Forms/")
                                                && !list.DefaultViewUrl.Contains("/FormServerTemplates/Forms/")
                                            )
                                        )
                                        {

                                            ListInfos listinfos = new ListInfos();

                                            ListInfo listinfo = new ListInfo();
                                            listinfo.GetListInfo(list, ref listinfos);

                                            WebInfo webinfo = new WebInfo();
                                            webinfo.GetWebInfos(web, ref listinfos);

                                            SiteInfo siteInfos = new SiteInfo();
                                            siteInfos.GetSiteCollectionInfo(site, ref listinfos);

                                            ApplicationInfo appInfo = new ApplicationInfo();
                                            appInfo.GetApplicationInfo(webApplication, ref listinfos);

                                            ContentDBInfo contentDBInfo = new ContentDBInfo();
                                            contentDBInfo.GetContentDBInfo(contentDatabase, ref listinfos);

                                            InsertApplicationStatus(listinfos);
                                            InsertContentDBStatus(listinfos);
                                            InsertSiteCollectionStatus(listinfos);
                                            InsertSitesStatus(listinfos);
                                            InsertListsStatus(listinfos);
                                            //InsertListinfo(listinfos);
                                            //PrintListInfo(listinfos);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    fileUtil.LogWrite(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I modify that code? or add code get site url....

Please help me.

Thank you